# Can SSH and hit Port 80 (w/ nginx listening), but cannot ping, or hit any other port (seemingly?)

Tags: networking, server

Banging my head on this all week, and as Friday reaches it's end, I have decided to ask the internet to see if anybody has any insight at all

I'm going to throw all the information I think could possibly be relevant, but I am also leaving out a lot of information which I figure is not relevant

---

I have a instance in the cloud running Ubuntu.
An engineer from another department set it up for me, and in order for me to ssh into it, I need to use a `.pem` key

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@IPOMITTED
```

To test my sanity, I installed nginx, and I successfully hit the welcome page when I hit the server w/
`$ curl http://IPOMITTED:80`

```
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

...
```

But, if I try to ping the server, it fails

```
ping IPOMITTED
PING IPOMITTED (IPOMITTED): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
...
```

Which whatever, might not be a problem.

The problem is, I'm trying to spin up a server called Sync Gateway, which listens on port 4984.

I am positive that I have installed it correctly, as I am able to hit it if I make a request locally.
I am not sure if I am missing some kind of configuration, here are two relevant lines in the config file for sync_gateway (but there really isn't anything else in this file)

```
"adminInterface": "127.0.0.1:4985",
"interface": ":4984",
```

Here is my net stat:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4985          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2148/sync_gateway
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1070/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::4984                 :::*                    LISTEN      2148/sync_gateway
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1070/sshd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           921/dhclient
```

Here is what I get when I make a local request:

```
$ curl localhost:4984
{"couchdb":"Welcome","vendor":{"name":"Couchbase Sync Gateway","version":"2.0"},"version":"Couchbase Sync Gateway/2.0.0(832;2d8a6c0)"}
```

But if I try to make the request remotely:

```
$ curl IPOMITTED:4984
curl: (7) Failed to connect to IPOMITTED port 4984: Operation timed out
```

Does anybody have any ideas how I can further debug this?  I have very little networking background, I'm from client engineering, so really any small idea would probably be helpful.

Thanks for your time!

EDIT:
Some more info as per @Steve:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

-

```
$ sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 276K packets, 17M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-7d807f03cf39  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-7d807f03cf39  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-7d807f03cf39 !br-7d807f03cf39  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-7d807f03cf39 br-7d807f03cf39  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 273K packets, 116M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-7d807f03cf39 !br-7d807f03cf39  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-7d807f03cf39  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: What if you try `”interface”: “0.0.0.0:4984”`? Also are you running a firewall? It may be blocking ICMP packets and anything not on ports 80 or 22. See if `ufw status verbose` reports anything, otherwise maybe look at the iptables rules specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :). I've updated the question with more info.  Also, I've tried 0.0.0.0:4984

Comment: There’s a line in your netstat output that looks like it’s only listening to port 4984 over IPv6, so can you try connecting with your IPv6 address rather than an IPv4 one?

Comment: no go :\ `curl -g -6 "http://[IP6OMITTED]:4984"
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`

Comment: I've filed a ticket with IT, I'm hoping at this point it's something on their end with the security around the cloud instance.  I just wish there was some way for me to get better error logging, at least see why my requests are failing

Comment: Yup, I lost a few days for nothing.  Real sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah uh, even though I had basically asked with this exact question and information, my server administrator had told me it wasn't a firewall issue.  But I came back to them and said to check again, and yes, it was as simple as adding an exception for port 4984.

I believe the confusion was when the administrator assumed I had done something wrong, and stopped listening when I explained that I was able to get a response from port 80, but not 4984

T.T

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.1:4985` means only localhost can access it, that is your first issue.

For network testing, you can open a simple connection with the `nc` command:

`nc -l -p 4984`

Then connect to it from a remote connection.  Try various ports.  It's likely a network firewall issue if this is 'in the cloud'.

Comment: Usually `nmap -PN $IPOMITTED` will give you all open ports, if you want to test a specific port, use `nmap -PN $IPOMITTED -p $PORT`.
Also, check [this tutorial](https://blog.jsinh.in/setup-couchbase-server-and-sync-gateway-on-ubuntu-2/) which make a case for `0.0.0.0` in config meaning is public

Comment: I don’t think the OP wants to make the admin interface public though.

Comment: Correct, I'm not worried about 4985 as it's the admin interface.  When I try the `nc` command, it appears to just hang, and when I try to make a request, I don't get a response anyways.  I agree with you, at this point I believe it to be a network firewall.  I'll hopefully get in touch with IT soon